# OptionsCaption not being removed after updating its observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Based on the knockout documentation, the way to remove the default text in a select element when using optionsCaption is to bind it to an observable and set that value to undefined e.g.

html:

```
<select id="category" data-bind="options: categoryTypes, value: categoryValue ... optionsCaption: categoryDefaultOptionText()"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
categoryDefaultOptionText("Please select"); //the value now displays in the select element with all categoryTypes.
...
...
...
categoryDefaultOptionText(undefined); //the default element is completely removed and only the categoryTypes are displayed.
```

My problem is that when setting `categoryDefaultOptionText(undefined);`, the default text is not removed from the select element. I've tested this in a jsfiddle and it works which leads me to believe something else is at fault.

The flow of the application is as follows:

1. Items are displayed on the page
2. Clicking an item opens up a new page
3. ajax call is made to a service to retrieve the categoryTypes lookup data
4. On success, they are populated in the categoryTypes observable, which is used in the data-bind options.
5. another ajax call is made and on success, the value the user selected, before for this item, is set as the current value `categoryValue("some value");`
6. while in this success method and after doing the previous step, set `categoryDefaultOptionText(undefined);`

One would expect this to work however 'Please select' remains. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've used Javascript to retrieve the select element and watched how it changed as I debugged. The "Please select" option is definitely being removed, however once the page is fully loaded, the combo box still has the "Please select" option available. Is it possible that because the page is not completely loaded, that changes cannot be made to it?

UPDATE 2:
I've discovered the issue. There was some other code that was interfering with the way the select element works when using optionsCaption. I'm not sure what to do with this question since it most likely will not be relevant to anyone else (the code was an unnecessary duplicated call)

Comment: Could you share the working jsfiddle  and another jsfiddle which replicates the error please?

Comment: try remove brackets here `optionsCaption: categoryDefaultOptionText()`

Comment: @Koshux I have been unable to replicate with a jsfiddle

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk I've just tried this and it does not work.

Comment: @Zubair check you create `categoryDefaultOptionText` observable only once and all assignments done with `categoryDefaultOptionText(newVal)` syntax